# Can't add a new schema in Kafka after deleting the old one

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to use a proper schema for keys too. By default, it is created as:

```
{"subject":"AVROTEST-key","version":1,"id":60,"schema":"\"string\""}
```

But I want it like:

```
{"subject":"AVROTEST-key","version":1,"id":60,"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"AVROTEST\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"key\",\"type\":\"long\"}]}"}
```

Because of the compatibility issues, I tried to delete it completely and add a new one. I've deleted it using

```
curl -X DELETE http://XXXXXX.XXXXXX:1234/subjects/AVROTEST-key/versions/1
```

there are no other versions and I get a 404 error when I try to GET it after deleting, which means it's deleted successfully. But when I try to register a new schema, I get this error:

> "error_code":409,"message":"Schema being registered is incompatible
> with an earlier schema"

How can it be incompatible with an earlier schema, while there is no schema? What am I missing?

This is how I register a new schema:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"AVROTEST\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":XXXXXX.XXXXXXXX:1234/subjects/AVROTEST-key/versions
```

Comment: 1) What version of the registry are you using? 2) Tell us more about the AVROTEST topic. Is there a producer actively writing to it? Why can't you change the topic name? You **should** change the topic name because you're invalidating all existing records in the topic if you've not otherwise cleared the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was another schema version which I didn't know about it. A funny mistake actually, I should've deleted all the versions, instead of [1]. So entering the command

```
curl -X DELETE http://XXXXXX.XXXXXX:1234/subjects/AVROTEST-key/versions/
```

solved my problem. All the previous schemas are deleted. But notice the new schema will not be registered as version [1]. It will increase the latest schema id.